# word order about how + p.p

Tags: usage

When I read these two sentences, (A) and (B), I notice the difference between them.  I want you to just confirm whether my understanding is correct.

(A) describes ***the degree*** to which people are persuaded whereas (B) ***the way, or the means*** people are persuaded. So, If I intend to mean ***the degree*** to which people are persuaded, I should write like (A), not (B), right?

> - (A) Framing of health messages influences ***how persuaded*** people are to engage in health promoting behaviors.
> - (B) Framing of health messages influences ***how*** people are ***persuaded*** to engage in health promoting behaviors.

Comment: You answered your own question when you said "(A) describes the degree to which people are persuaded. Note that in (A) "how" is a modifier of "persuaded", while in (B) "how" introduces the fused relative construction "how people are persuaded to engage in health promoting behaviors".

Comment: I can't find either sentence in the book you link to.

Comment: There is a problem with your link that I cannot seem to fix.

Comment: https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=e1mLpivtC3IC&pg=RA1-PA157&lpg=RA1-PA157&dq=(e.g.,+%22Research+shows+that+women+who+do+breast+self-exam+have+an+increased+chance+of+finding+a+tumor+in+the+early,+more+treatable+stage+of+the+disease,%22&source=bl&ots=BPobSB-5zN&sig=ACfU3U2xFFPgpnFm17tpaFzJzJ-kd4Moxw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1gtz0r8-BAxUUPnAKHZIqAPoQ6AF6BAgKEAM#v=onepage&q=(e.g.%2C%20%22Research%20shows%20that%20women%20who%20do%20breast%20self-exam%20have%20an%20increased%20chance%20of%20finding%20a%20tumor%20in%20the%20early%2C%20more%20treatable%20stage%20of%20the%20disease%2C%22&f=false

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I wrongly linked and now I tried to correct it but failed repeatedly.